# Zend Studio problem

Tags: zend-studio

I installed Zend Studio on Windows 7. When i Start the Program one example project is automatically created. But When i run in browser i get this error :-

```
Cannot connect to the configuration database.
```

I think there is no Web server configured for it. Then i downloaded Apache web server and extracted the zip folder. Now how do i link this apache web server to Zend Studio? How do i start Apache Web Server from within Zend Studio? Please let me know anything is not clear.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This appears to belong to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Zend Server (there is also a Community Edition) should simplify your work

Answer (score 1):

I think that database is used for the sample project. so not setting it makes no sense.
Just for your need, try [installing zend debugger](http://static.zend.com/topics/Debugger-Install.pdf) made for apache and configure that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a backtrace of where that error is occurring or does it pop up in a Window?

Answer (score 0):

You can start Apache Web Server from Zend Studio by doing below steps.

1. Open Zend Studio.
2. Go to Window | Show View | PHP | Server.
3. Click on New button and Select Local Apache HTTP Server.
4. Click Next and fill the requested server details.

For details, you can refer: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/adding_a_php_server.htm

Once the configuration process is successful you can create a PHP project (File | New | Local PHP project) with Apache web server as you PHP Server.